# put php commands in php string

Tags: php, file

I have admin panel in which I can create categories. When I create categories I auto create folders in htdocs... for example... categorie/first , categorie/second and so on

And what I want to do, is that when I create these folders I auto create index.php with code I need... First variant is using file functions... but then how do I put in string php commands?
second.. and I guess the right one, is to create this template.. and when I create these folders it copies to directory I created...

So what you think?

edit...
BUT I need to store in this code variable with current categorie opened.

Comment: edit... BUT I need to store in this code variable with current categorie opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to write your code like that :

```
// Creates a template of category
$page = <<< EOT

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Category {$category_name}</title>
        (...)

    </body>
</html>
EOT;

$f = fopen($new_directory . "/index.php", 'w');
fwrite($f, $page);
fclose($f);
```

Remeber to put EOT; at the very left side of your document. See the [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for details.

This code is a sample, you need of course to check if fopen/fwrite have succeeded.

Another solution could be to have a template in another file with template tokens.

In such way, you will have a file named template_category.txt which contains :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Category %category_name%</title>
        (...)

    </body>
</html>
```

Then, in your PHP script, you'll do replace template tokens by your values :

```
$template = file_get_contents("template_category.txt");

$to_replace = array(
    '%category_name%',
    (...)
);

$replace_by = array(
    $category_name,
    (...)
);

$page = str_replace($to_replace, $replace_by, $template);
```

And you write $page on index.php like above.

Comment: but can I write there echo / str_replace()... commands like these I mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try a template file with php- and html- code and specify there needed vars with some tokens, like:

```
in template.php
<?php
$category_id = #TOKEN_CATEGORY_ID#;
...
?>
```

Then copy this file into new category's folder and do preg_replace() on the #TOKEN_CATEGORY_ID#.